# NodeJS Group Functions Under A Sub-Class

Tags: javascript, node.js

perhaps I have not worded the title correctly. Below is the explanation of what I'm trying to do.

I'm creating a helper.js file for my project. Inside it contains many functions, one I've pasted below. I export this function using module.exports.

```
function generateInternalError(message, stack_trace) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'dev') {
        console.log({ message: message, stack_trace: stack_trace });
    } else {
        console.log({message: message});
    }
}

module.exports = {
    generateInternalError: generateInternalError
};
```

Where I want to utilize this function I would call:

```
helper.generateInternalError('Not Found',new Error().stack);
```

And it works as expected.

But, what I have been tasked with, is creating categories of functions. Essentially I need the following:

```
helper.errors.generateInternalError('Not Found',new Error().stack);
```

I can not seem to figure out the right way to export a class of functions or an object of functions in NodeJS such that I don't get an error like:

```
TypeError: helper.errors.generateClientError is not a function
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `module.exports = { errors: { generateInternalError } };`

Comment: @4castle, this worked great! Is there any way to also write the functions inside of one structure?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but you can add more functions with just a comma and another key/value pair inside the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to structure your helper sub classes in separate files.

### Example

src/helpers.js
src/helpers/
src/helpers/errors.js

**File** *helpers.js*

```
module.exports = {
   errors: require('./helpers/errors')
}
```

**File** *helpers/errors.js*

```
module.exports = {
    generateInternalError: function(){
        //write some internal error code here
    }
};
```

Structuring your code like this will keep your root helpers file very organized and create a pattern that is easy to replicate for new subclasses.

If you prefer a less modular approach you could simply just return one big JSON object as other's have demonstrated...

```
module.exports = {
    errors: {
        generateInternalError: function(){
            //internal error code
        },
        generateDatabaseError: function(){
            //db error code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the use-case in the question, "static method" is what they want, which means using `prototype` or the `class` syntax wouldn't be appropriate. (Though I'm also of the opinion that `class` is [never appropriate](https://github.com/joshburgess/not-awesome-es6-classes))

Comment: Yes, I put in an example for both static and dynamic methods after I read the ops question again.

Comment: Not sure why the -2, as I've answered the ops question and provided multiple alternatives to learn from.

Comment: I think the downvotes are coming because the advice is not very good. The first code snippet is good, but snippets 2, 3, and 4 are all misleading.

Comment: Yes, perhaps a bit tricky to navigate considering the novice nature of the question.

Answer (score 4):

The `module.exports` property of a file is simply an object that maps names to functions. You can define it arbitrarily, for example:

```
module.exports = {
    errors: {
        generateInternalError,
        ...
    },
    ...
};
```

Then, `require('./helper').errors.generateInternalError` will be defined.

Answer (score 1):

`helpers` is just noise if everything is a helper, so drop that.  Just use regular modules and unless you are sure you only have one function in that category export multiple functions.  If you only export one function with module.exports then you don't need to do that as a property of an object which also means you can just say `const genError=require('./errors')`

Don't make something like `helpers.errors.someErrorFunc` because helpers is noise and you make categories with just separate module files.  Don't try to make Node.js look like Java or something equally horrible.